# Deploying Wildfly EJB via mvn wildfly:deploy not putting jar into local repo. Ejb client can't see ejb dependency

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly-8

I'm trying to run an [example](https://github.com/nazerke/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka) from "Java EE 7 Development with Wildfly". First I've deployed ticket-agency-ejb itself via `mvn wildfly:deploy`, but it didn't install the jar into local repo, so I did `mvn install` even though it isn't mentioned in the book.I can see the jar in the local repo as expected. But then I tried to run ticket-agency-ejb-client via `mvn package install exec:exec` but getting this error:

> Failed to execute goal on project ticket-agency-ejb-client: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency-ejb-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency-ejb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Could not find artifact
>   com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3:ticket-agency:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   -> [Help 1]

Then I did `mvn deploy` in parent project(ticket-agency) and tried to run the client again, it now works as intended. Now I'm confused

1) why `mvn wildfly:deploy` didn't put jar into local repo?

2) why deploying the parent was necessary?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to gain an understanding of maven lifecycles. According to [wildfly:deploy](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html), the maven lifecycle phase `package` is invoked before the artifact is deployed to WildFly. `package` creates the jar, but does not install it in the local repository. This happens during the subsequent `install` phase.
2. "deploying" the parent was not necessary. The `deploy` phase follows the `install` phase. This means that you installed all child modules in the local repository prior to the `deploy`. Running `mvn install` on the parent would have had the same effect. Note that the maven deploy process uploads artifacts to your repository manager. It does not deploy anything to your application server.
3. You must perform at least one `mvn install` from the parent because the two child poms are dependent upon it. This will install the parent pom.xml in your local repository.

Here it is with your own project:

```
[steve@steves-mbp ticket-agency]$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ticket-agency
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb-client
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ticket-agency 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ticket-agency ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ticket-agency ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/pom.xml to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency/1.0/ticket-agency-1.0.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ticket-agency-ejb 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Building EJB ticket-agency-ejb with EJB version 3.2
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb.jar
[INFO] Building EJB client ticket-agency-ejb-client
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb-client.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb.jar to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency-ejb/1.0/ticket-agency-ejb-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/pom.xml to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency-ejb/1.0/ticket-agency-ejb-1.0.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb-client.jar to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency-ejb/1.0/ticket-agency-ejb-1.0-client.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ticket-agency-ejb-client 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/target/ticket-agency-ejb-client-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/target/ticket-agency-ejb-client-1.0.jar to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency-ejb-client/1.0/ticket-agency-ejb-client-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb-client/pom.xml to /Users/steve/.m2/repository/com/packtpub/wflydevelopment/chapter3/ticket-agency-ejb-client/1.0/ticket-agency-ejb-client-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ticket-agency ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.204 s]
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb .................................. SUCCESS [  1.346 s]
[INFO] ticket-agency-ejb-client ........................... SUCCESS [  0.282 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.005 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-08T19:29:30+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/230M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[steve@steves-mbp ticket-agency]$ mvn -pl ticket-agency-ejb wildfly:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ticket-agency-ejb 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) > package @ ticket-agency-ejb >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
[INFO] Building EJB ticket-agency-ejb with EJB version 3.2
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb.jar
[INFO] Building EJB client ticket-agency-ejb-client
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/steve/work/personal/wildflydevelopmentbycmilandmatloka/ticket-agency/ticket-agency-ejb/target/ticket-agency-ejb-client.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) < package @ ticket-agency-ejb <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ ticket-agency-ejb ---
Oct 08, 2015 7:30:03 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Oct 08, 2015 7:30:03 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Oct 08, 2015 7:30:03 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.737 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-08T19:30:05+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/369M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[steve@steves-mbp ticket-agency]$ mvn -pl ticket-agency-ejb-client exec:exec
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ticket-agency-ejb-client 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ ticket-agency-ejb-client ---
Theatre booking system
=====================================
Commands: book, bookasync, list, mail, money, quit
> list
Oct 08, 2015 7:30:35 PM com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3.client.TicketAgencyClient handleList
INFO: Seat [id=1, name=Stalls, price=40, booked=false]
Seat [id=2, name=Circle, price=20, booked=false]
Seat [id=3, name=Balcony, price=10, booked=false]
Seat [id=4, name=Stalls, price=40, booked=false]
Seat [id=5, name=Circle, price=20, booked=false]
Seat [id=6, name=Balcony, price=10, booked=false]
Seat [id=7, name=Stalls, price=40, booked=false]
Seat [id=8, name=Circle, price=20, booked=false]
Seat [id=9, name=Balcony, price=10, booked=false]
Seat [id=10, name=Stalls, price=40, booked=false]
Seat [id=11, name=Circle, price=20, booked=false]
Seat [id=12, name=Balcony, price=10, booked=false]
Seat [id=13, name=Stalls, price=40, booked=false]
Seat [id=14, name=Circle, price=20, booked=false]
Seat [id=15, name=Balcony, price=10, booked=false]

>
```

Comment: 1. Thank you pointing out in the source, I've just assumed that every phase  before deploy happens as in mvn deploy. Then I don't understand why the book didn't mention "mvn install", because clearly the client ejb looks for the ejb in the local repo, and it doesn't find it, hence the error
2.As I understood, the necessary steps are: in ejb - mvn wildfly:deploy, mvn install, and in ejb client - mvn package install exec:exec. Is it so? If it is, as I mentioned in the question, it didn't work and resulted in the error. Only when I did mvn deploy in parent project, did it work.

Comment: in ejb - `mvn install wildfly:deploy`, and in ejb client - `mvn install exec:exec`. Maven executes each phase listed in the order shown up until and including the one you specify on the command line. These two commands process the lifecycle up until the specified phase `install` is completed, and then executes the plugin goals `wildly:deploy` or `exec:exec`.

Comment: So it confirms what I did. I tried as  said once more, but still getting the error in question. I.e. it doesn't work until I do mvn:deploy in parent(ticket-agency).So the second part of my question remains open

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be an answer or not (I'm new to EJB), but for me the project did not run until I changed the poms. **Also I don't understand Why there is nothing in my wildfly standalone folder?** Looks like I'm reading the same book, and it was very hard to past through this point. So what I did is to look at this example: 
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/ejb-remote
It worked from the first time going through the README file. Here are the main steps for these kind of projects:

> ```
> Make sure you have started the WildFly server. See the instructions in the previous section.
> Open a command prompt and navigate to the ejb-remote quickstart directory
> ```

```
Build and install the server side component:

    Navigate to the server-side subdirectory:

    cd server-side

    Build the EJB and client interfaces JARs and install them in your local Maven repository.

    mvn clean install        

    Deploy the EJB JAR to your server. This Maven goal will deploy server-side/target/wildfly-ejb-remote-server-side.jar. You can check the WildFly server console to see information messages regarding the deployment.

    mvn wildfly:deploy

Build and run the client application

    Navigate to the client subdirectory:

    cd ../client

    Compile the client code

    mvn clean compile

    Execute the client application within Maven

    mvn exec:exec
```

I will post also the three modified pom xmls files (these are with wildfly 10 beta 2):

ticket-agency pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3</groupId>
<artifactId>ticket-agency</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstart: ticket-agency</name>

<properties>
    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<!-- This quickstart consists of a server side component and a client that accesses
 the server side component. Each component has its own self contain pom. However,
 you can add these modules here to keep things modular.
 -->
<modules>
    <module>ticket-agency-ejb</module>
    <module>ticket-agency-ejb-client</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- The WildFly plug-in deploys your apps to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- Disabling it here means that we don't try to deploy this POM! -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ticket-agency-ejb pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3</groupId>
<artifactId>ticket-agency-ejb</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstart: ejb-remote - server-side</name>
<url>http://wildfly.org</url>

<properties>
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    <version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>1.0.3.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>
    <!-- other plug-in versions -->
    <version.ejb.plugin>2.3</version.ejb.plugin>
    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss Java EE APIs we want to use -->
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE APIs including a Bill 
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0 stack (you can read this as 
            the JBoss stack of the Java EE APIs). You can actually use this stack with 
            any version of WildFly that implements Java EE. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
        as the API is included in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Set the name of the deployment -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- WildFly plug-in to deploy the application -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <!-- this is false by default -->
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

ticket-agency-ejb-client pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket-agency</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>ticket-agency-ejb-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>WildFly Quickstart: ticket-agency-ejb-client</name>
<description>WildFly Quickstarts: Java client for remote EJB</description>
<url>http://wildfly.org</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <version.wildfly>10.0.0.Beta2</version.wildfly>
    <version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>1.0.3.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0>

    <!-- WildFly Maven plug-in to deploy your WAR to a local WildFly container -->
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>


    <!-- other plug-in versions -->
    <version.exec.plugin>1.2.1</version.exec.plugin>
    <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

    <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
     <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 7 APIs we want to use -->
     <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including
        a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
        a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
        versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0 stack (you can
        read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs). You can actually
        use this stack with any version of WildFly that implements Java EE 7, not
        just WildFly 8! -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
         <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
         <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
         <type>pom</type>
         <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Import the transaction spec API, we use runtime scope because
        we aren't using any direct reference to the spec API in our client code -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use runtime scope because we aren't using
        any direct reference to EJB spec API in our client code -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- We depend on the EJB remote business interfaces of this application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3</groupId>
        <artifactId>ticket-agency-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
   </dependency>

    <!-- Include the ejb client jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Client communications with the server use XNIO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
        <artifactId>xnio-api</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
        <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.remoting3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Remote EJB security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.sasl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-sasl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data serialization for remote EJBs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Add the maven exec plug-in to allow us to run a java program
            via maven -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.exec.plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exec-working-directory</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
                        also adding the project build directory -->
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath>
                    </classpath>
                    <argument>com.packtpub.wflydevelopment.chapter3.client.TicketAgencyClient</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```